# Passing variables to different view controllers

Tags: cocoa-touch

I've searched and searched but nothing has really worked.

I'm trying to set a textvalue from a text box, into a string or whatever, so that I can call it up later in a different view controller. I can't seem to get it to work!

I'd also like numbers to be carried over, such like currency's.

Any ideas on them?

Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could make an instance variable on the other view controller retain or copy the value before you push/pop the view. For example:

```
OpenNextViewController *varNextPageController = [[OpenNextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OpenNextViewController" bundle:nil];
varNextPageController .textString= self.textString;
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:varNextPageController animated:YES];
[varNextPageController release];
```

In "OpenNextViewController" in this example have an instance variable "textString" that retains or copies (depending on your needs) your text.

Comment: Yup, I'm doing something similar in my project. Just pay close attention to retain vs copy.

Answer (score 3):

Spend some time trying to grok the [Model View Controller](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/chapter_5_section_4.html) pattern.

In your case you may be looking to share data between different views sharing a common Model.  The Model is the store of your data, in your case the textvalue.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague. Could you give any more specifics.
It *sounds* like you want to know:

1. How to get values from controls. In the case of a text field there should be a text property you can get the value from.
2. How to share values between controllers. Not sure exactly what you mean. The *controller* usually orchestrates the sharing of values between different *views* by using a *model* as the authoritative version of the data.

Again, if you can be any more specific we may be able to help more

Comment: Right, I've got about 3 view controllers. each with their own view. On the first view controller I've got a text field, I can get the text out from it using NSString *variable and whatever, but I don't know how to get this string over to another view controller where I want to bring it up.

Comment: looks like you have an "accepted" answers now - but from what you've said it does look like you're missing a "model" concept (as also highlighted by some other answers).

Answer (score 0):

If you want it in several controllers, then I would think you need to run it through the model?

Answer (score 0):

Do you guys think that using the AppDelegate as the holder for one's model is fundamentally wrong? I mean AppDelegate is easily visible to all controllers so it's easy to bind to and get/set it's properties.

pom

Comment: I'd recommend asking this as a separate question to get answers.