# Sharing a NSString between two views

Tags: ios, xcode, ios4

I need to share a string between two views in my application. When the user ends the game, the score is converted into a string. I then need to transfer that string into a different view controller where I display the score. I have a label set up and all but the view is not recognizing the string even though I am importing the header file from which the string is created. Any help would be great, thank.

This is my view controller where the string is created

```
NSString *scoreString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", score];
```

And this is where I try to display the string in a different view controller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.scoreString = score.text;

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: Show us the code where you are defining your string and assigning it to the label.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For scores and similar data, you may want to use `NSUserDefaults`. These can be accessed at any time from any UIViewController. For example, you can implement methods similar to these to save and retrieve the data:

```
-(void)saveToUserDefaults:(NSString*)myString
{
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if (standardUserDefaults) {
        [standardUserDefaults setObject:myString forKey:@"Score"];
        [standardUserDefaults synchronize];
    }
}

-(NSString*)retrieveFromUserDefaults
{
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *val = nil;

    if (standardUserDefaults) 
        val = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"Score"];

    return val;
}
```

`NSUserDefaults` also handles `int`s, `BOOL`s, `NSArray`s, etc. Check out [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or google around for examples.

Comment: How do I move the string into NSUserDefaults? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, the NSUser Default is working great but now how do I set the score.text to equal the objectForKey:@"Score"?

Comment: @MacN00b Just put `score.text` where my code reads `myString`.

Comment: Ok this is what I did,                                       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"message" forKey:@"Score"]; Then I retrive it by doing this [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Score"]; But now I am trying to put that value into the text box and by doing self.message = score.text; but I get the error Property 'message' not found on object of type 'ViewController'. Any idea why?

Comment: @MacN00b: there is no `self.message` unless you have declared and synthesized an `NSString` called `message`. Try using the methods I defined above and calling `[self saveToUserDefaults:score.text];` and then `score.text = [self retrieveFromUserDefaults];`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use delegates or NSUserDefaults

Been asked similiar questions before:

[Passing variables to different view controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453406/passing-variables-to-different-view-controllers)

[How do I pass variables between view controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383101/how-do-i-pass-variables-between-view-controllers)

### EDIT

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"STRING HERE" forKey:@"MyKey"];
```

and retrieve

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"MyKey"];
```

Comment: How do I move the string into NSUserDefaults? Thanks.

Comment: Ok I got That working, now how do I use this to display the string in my label? Thanks